# How to Change Color of Bootstrap Borders?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Been trying to figure out how to change the color of my Bootstrap border, without using the generic bootstrap colors (aka

> `<span class="border border-primary"></span>`

so I tried giving my `border` an id, and styling that id in the .CSS file as `border-color: yellow;` and `color: yellow`; to no avail. The code is not working. Although `background-color: yellow;` works fine just not working the border itself.

Here's my code:

```css
.iconBorder {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<span class="border border-primary">Button</span>
<span class="border-bottom p-4 m-2 d-inline-block" style="margin-top: em" id="iconBorder">
```

Comment: Try `#iconBorder { border-color: yellow;  }` - since it's id

Comment: @A.Meshu this `#iconBorder { border-color: yellow;  }` won't work without putting `!important` at the end of the color

Comment: @Gad i didn't read the bootstrap 4 css file (yet) but i think that if you declare your css rules after you load the boots it would work without `!important`.

Comment: Bootstrap can be overriden by simply placing your new styles `after` bootstraps, whether that be at the bottom of the bootstrap file or in another file, loaded after bootstrap. No need to go digging yourself a hole with `!important` tags in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer regarding `!important`. Also, your CSS has

```
.iconBorder {
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

`.iconBorder` is a ***class***. your HTML has 'iconBorder' as an ***ID***.

So your CSS should use a hashtag:

```
#iconBorder {
    border-color: yellow;
}
```

This might not solve the problem (see !important) but it could help, and FYI.

Comment: I believe the issue was the fact an ID was used and the CSS used a class selector. Simply loading your own CSS `after` you load Bootstrap would eliminates the use of lots of `!important` tags throughout your CSS file, which for me, has caused only more headache further on into the development of a project.

Comment: Doesn't always work. It's about *specificity* as much as order of loading.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the selector structure is also something to consider.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override any default properties of bootstrap you have to make those properties as [`!important`](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

### Example

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.border {
  margin: 10px;
}

.border-primary:nth-child(1) {
  border-color: green !important;
}

.border-primary:nth-child(2) {
  border-color: yellow !important;
}

.border-primary:nth-child(3) {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <span class="border border-primary">Button</span>
  <span class="border border-primary">Button</span>
  <span class="border border-primary">Button</span>
</div>
```